# Measurability of the sum of measurable function and $L^p$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

Let $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ a measurable space. Let $f,g: X\rightarrow\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ two measurable functions in X.

The sum of two measurable functions is well defined (and measurable) only where there is no $+\infty -\infty$ situation (which may occurs because in measure theory we're working on the real extended number). In this point the sum is not defined.

The fact is that I cannot understand how we can say that the spaces $\mathcal{L}^p(X)$ are vector space. I mean the sum of two elements in $\mathcal{L}^p(X)$ is a function that is generally measurable only in subset of X.

Hope is clear.

Thanks

Comment: The space $\mathcal{L}^p(X)$ is defined to have only function that are finite a.e. Then, it is the space ${L}^p(X)$ (the quocient space of $\mathcal{L}^p(X)$ by the subspace of function null a.e.) that is the vector space.